# woocommerce hook on custom order status changed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

hey I was trying to make a plugin that sends WhatsApp messages on order status change so this is my code

```
add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "order_status_wapp",10,3); 
function order_status_wapp($order_id, $old_status, $new_status){  
 if( $new_status == "processing" && carbon_get_theme_option( 'show_processing' )) {       require("incl/apicall.php");  
$message = carbon_get_theme_option( 'processing_message' );       
require("incl/message_attr.php");            
}
```

the code is working well when changing the status from the order table area ( actions ), but changing the status from the order details or programmatically shows no effect. is there any hook that triggers status change no matter what the way of changing is?

Comment: You can use woocommerce_order_status_(from)_to_(to) where from is current status and to is the new status.  Another one is woocommerce_order_payment_status_changed  which fires when status is pending payment and we change to a paid one. You can look in the docs for more info about these hooks. Depends on your needs there are plenty of hooks to use.

Comment: @MartinMirchev the woocommerce_order_status_(from)_to_(to) hook is the same as woocommerce_order_status_changed only fires when the change has been made from the orders table action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, it worked.

My issue was that I was testing the event with the ACF Update field, which did not work.

However, when I changed it to the main event (send SMS), it worked perfectly.